# Fechar o InAppBrowser Phonegap

Tags: apache-cordova

Consigo abrir a URL dentro do InAppBrowser, porém ao clicar com o botão do aparelho para retornar, deveria fechar a janela, mas não fecha.
Isso porque peguei o exemplo completo do site do Phonegap e não alterei ele em nada.
Como faço para encerrar ele, seja clicando com o botão voltar do aparelho ou de outra forma?

Abaixo esta o código completo, retirado do site Phonegap.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas de solucionar esse problema.

De acordo com a documentação ao utilizar o `window.open` você recebe um objeto da janela criada. E neste objeto temos o método `close`.
Então basta chamar o método para fechar a janela.

```
ref.close();
```

O problema é saber quando chamar este método.
Para isso podemos utilizar um `eventListener` do botão voltar do Android.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", ref.close, false);
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema, porém existe uma alternativa que pode ser utilizar e apresentar um resultado melhor.

Você pode utilizar jQuery ou algum *framework* para manipular o DOM.
Desta forma todo o seu aplicativo pode rodar em uma página. Basicamente você cria todo o conteúdo em divs com `display:none`, o que torna invisível no inicio do aplicativo.
Feito isso basta criar botões e utilizar JavaScript para alternar a visibilidade dos elementos e criar a página.

Vale mencionar que com isso a liberdade é imensa, caso você precisar de algum conteúdo externo, basta requisitar por meio de AJAX.

Em um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo criei algo neste estilo, criei uma página unica em HTML com todo o conteúdo pré-definido. Ao apresentar a *SplashScreen* carrego todo o conteúdo do aplicativo por meio de JSONP e utilizando um pequeno template engine em JavaScript crio o conteúdo das páginas.
Como resultado, o aplicativo se tornou extremamente rápido, fácil de desenvolver e em momento algum a tela chega a ficar branca esperando algum conteúdo carregar. Já que com o uso de *callbacks* posso apresentar um conteúdo para o usuário assim que o mesmo se torna disponivel.